# the "Children" of nested files

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nested

I'm doing a project (on Django REST Framework) dedicated to file storage. The project structure assumes that folders can be nested in other folders. And files can be nested in folders. I have prescribed the logic of the file link to the folder in which it is uploaded. However, I need that when I request the service via the API, I am given another field that includes the data of all subfolders and files (the "children") field.

My model.py file:

```
FILE='FILE'
FOLDER='FOLDER'
TYPE_CHOICES = [(FILE,"FILE"),(FOLDER,"FOLDER")]




class Folder(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, editable=False, default='FOLDER')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    # size = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default = 0)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)



class File(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, editable=False, default='FILE')
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    file = models.FileField(null=True, max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now =True)
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parentId = models.ForeignKey(Folder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file.name)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, please improve your question. Be more specific and clarify the problem.

Comment: @NKSM 
I am implementing a file storage project on Django REST Framework. The project implies that it will be possible to upload files, put them in folders and then download them via the API. The files and folders in my project have a column "parentID", which indicates which folder this file/folder is attached to. I need that when a request is made via the API of a certain folder, not only information about this folder, but also information from subfolders and files is transmitted in the response to the request. If something is not clear, please clarify what exactly.

Comment: I think you should also add your serializers and views